# Gvim showing white rectangles for spaces at some places

Tags: vim

This is what I see in `gvim` after I copy-pasted text there. I do not see it in `vim` in terminal. What does this mean? I am clueless as whether it is a bug or a feature:)

[image]

Comment: Are they a selection highlights? I don't recognize the theme but you can try  to `:noh` to find if I'm right

Comment: What is the output of these commands? `:set list?` and `:set listchars`

Comment: It looks like what happens for some of my themes when I'm in space mode and copy in tabs '\t'

Comment: It might simply be whitespace.  You can use `ga` to see whether it is space or tab, or `:set ruler`:  if you see something like "1-4" in the ruler, then it is a tab.  Use the example under `:help synID()` to check the highlight group:  `:echo synIDattr(synID(line("."), col("."), 1), "name")`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I dedicated some more time to this. It seems to be a bug. It has nothing to do with white spaces. It happens when:

1. Editing .html file
2. Just inside  tags
3. The color scheme is "slate"

I solved it simply by changing the color scheme.